# jquery form post not worked

Tags: jquery

I want post a form with jquery, but my code not work. after I submit it, my page will refresh, where is the problem? wait for a help.

jquery code

```
function submitForm() {
        var par1 = $('input[@name=my_radio][@checked]').val();
        var par2 = $('input[@name=title]').val();
        var par3 = $('input[@name=content]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "r8.php", 
                dataType: "html",
                type: 'POST', 
                data: "submit=" + par1 + "&title=" + par2 + "&content=" + par3, 
                success: function(data){ 
                    $("#response").html(data);
                    $('input[@name=title]').html('');
                    $('input[@name=content]').html('');
                }
            });

        return false;
    }
```

html code:

```
<form method="post" id="post_form" name="post_form" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <label>1: <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="1" checked /></label>   
    <label>2: <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="2" /></label> 
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text">
    <input id="content" name="content" type="text">
    <input type="submit" name="my_submit" id="my_submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

and r8.php code

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']!=''){ 

    echo $_POST['title']."|".$_POST['content']."|".$_POST['submit']."|".time(); 

}
?>
```

Comment: If you are seeing the page refresh when your submit handler is returning false, then the problem is usually a JavaScript error in the submit handler function.  I don't see anything obvious there.  Run the script using a debugger.  Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your java script submitform() function, recieve values like this:

```
var par1 = $('input:radio[name=my_radio]:checked').val()
var par2 = $('#title').val();
var par3 = $('#content').val();
```

your method is not getting the values in the variables. thats why nothing is being posted.
I've tried it and it works.

EDIT:

What you would need to do is use one of the ajax methods to post your form, and inject the output into an element within the success callback. For example:

```
$("#my_submit").click(function() {
    $.post($("#post_form").attr("action"), $("#post_form").serialize(), function(html) {
        $("div.post_form").html(html);
    });
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

Take a look at

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
and
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

give r8.php in your form action attribute. i.e.

```
<form method="post" id="post_form" name="post_form" action="r8.php" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem with you selectors..
remove "@" from the selector and it will work..

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function submitForm() {

             var par1 = $('input[name=my_radio][checked]').val();
         var par2 = $("input[name=title]").val();
         var par3 = $("input[name=content]").val();

         $.ajax({
                 url: "r8.php", 
                 dataType: "html",
                 type: 'POST', 
                 data: "submit=" + par1 + "&title=" + par2 + "&content=" + par3, 
                 success: function(data){ 
                     $("#response").html(data);
                     $("input[name=title]").html("");
                     $("input[name=content]").html("");
                                          }
                  });

                   return false;
               } 

     </script>
```